# CompressionTest for LZO fails

Tags: hadoop, hbase, lzo

I sincerely thank you for reading my post.

I'm trying to install LZO 2.03 compression codec on HBase on my server (running Xeon CPUs).
I'm currently running Hadoop 0.20.1 with HBase 0.90.2.

I've followed the guidelines from http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UsingLzoCompression. And I downloaded the LZO native connector (Hadoop-GPL-Compression) from http://code.google.com/p/hadoop-gpl-compression/.

I installed the lzo library using `./configure --prefix=/home/ckwon/wks/test/lzo_lib_x64 --enable-shared --disable-asm --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`

(with `make install` to a custom directory).

And then I copied all of LZO library files and GPL-Compression files (including native/) to $HADOOP_HOME/lib/ and $HBASE_HOME/lib

Then I ran the bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CompressionTest with the following script:

```
setenv CLASSPATH_HBASEI    `ls ${HBASE_HOME}/*.jar |& awk '{printf( ":%s", $1 );}'`
setenv CLASSPATH_HBASELIBI `ls ${HBASE_HOME}/lib/*.jar |& awk '{printf( ":%s", $1 );}'`
setenv CLASSPATH_LZO  $HBASE_HOME/lib/native/liblzo2.so

setenv CLASSPATH ${CLASSPATH_HBASEI}${CLASSPATH_HBASELIBI}

setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH64 $HBASE_HOME/lib/native
#setenv LD_LIBRARY $HBASE_HOME/lib/native

ls -l $LD_LIBRARY_PATH64

set JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java

set   JAVA_PLATFORM=`CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH};${JAVA} org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName | sed -e "s/ /_/g"`
echo JP=$JAVA_PLATFORM

set      JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=${HBASE_HOME}/lib/native/${JAVA_PLATFORM}
echo
echo java_lib_path---
echo
echo $JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH

cd $HBASE_HOME
./bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CompressionTest hdfs://SERVER:PORT/COMPRESSION_TEST_RUNNER.sh lzo
```

And it's generating

```
INFO lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
WARN lzo.LzoCompressor: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load liblzo2.so.2 (liblzo2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)!
ERROR lzo.LzoCodec: Failed to load/initialize native-lzo library
    java.lang.RuntimeException: native-lzo library not available
            at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec.getCompressorType(LzoCodec.java:135)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:98)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.Compression$Algorithm.getCompressor(Compression.java:200)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile$Writer.getCompressingStream(HFile.java:397)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile$Writer.newBlock(HFile.java:383)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile$Writer.checkBlockBoundary(HFile.java:354)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile$Writer.append(HFile.java:536)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile$Writer.append(HFile.java:515)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CompressionTest.main(CompressionTest.java:126)
```

I've tried rebuilding the LZO library in x86_64-pc w/ i386 assembly code disabled, but is still causing the error.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you put the shared objects into the lib/native/ folder?

Comment: I'm also having trouble building the shared objects.  Did you check to see that they were generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the native LZO libraries on both the master and slave servers. E.g. on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install liblzo2-dev
```

If you have problems after following the [Cloudera setup instructions](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/11/hadoop-at-twitter-part-1-splittable-lzo-compression/), try copying the libgplcompression* files into your Hadoop lib folder.  On Ubuntu, assuming you followed the Cloudera setup instructions, this would be:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/lib/libgplcompression.* \
    /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/
```